# Mongodb hash type keys return 'null' value in array

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, hash, doctrine-orm

Can someone help pls? I am using doctrine_mongodb and I am trying to obtain the values of all keys in my document. I get the values of the fields with types integer, string and boolean but my fields of type hash return a value of 'null'

Here is how I define one of the hash fields in class Scripts of /documents/Scripts.php

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="scripts")
 */
class Scripts
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    public $id;
   /** 
     * @MongoDB\Hash
     */
    public $properties;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. For me the Hydrator was cached with old values, and it wasn't referencing any of the new ones I added.

`app/console cache:clear
app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents BUNDLENAME`

Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed now. I manually created the hash type fields in "/var/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev/doctrine/odm/mongodb/Hydrators/AtlasMpBundleDocumentScriptsHydrator.php" with php type array. It is pretty easy to understand when you open the file.

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: Generated hydrator and proxy classes should not be manually modified. In fact, both include "THIS CLASS WAS GENERATED BY THE DOCTRINE ODM. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE" at the top of each file. If you're attempting to add logic so that the hash field always contains properties within it, you most likely want to use embedded documents and create a Properties model in your case with the appropriate mapped fields within.

Answer (score 0):

Functional test [GH453Test.php](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/tests/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Tests/Functional/Ticket/GH453Test.php) in the ODM project includes an example of using a hash-mapped field. If you're seeing a `null` property after your model is hydrated, it is because the field does not exist or its value is `null` in the document returned from MongoDB. The conversion logic is rather straightforward in [HashType::convertToPHPValue()](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Types/HashType.php).